# Inconsistent boundary and initial conditions: BC ignored altogether

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

Consider the following diffusion-decay equation with von Neumann b/c in the origin and Dirichlet at the other boundary:

```
pde = D[u[x, t], t] == d*D[u[x, t], x, x] - \[Delta]*u[x, t]
bc = {D[u[x, t], x] == -j0 /. x -> 0, u[x, t] == 0 /. x -> length}
ic = u[x, t] == u0 /. t -> 0
params = {d -> 10, \[Delta] -> 1, length -> 600, u0 -> 200, j0 -> 4000}
tFinal = 150;
soln = NDSolve[Flatten@{pde, bc, ic} /. params, u, {t, 0, tFinal}, {x, 0, length /. params}]
```

Running NDSolve as above generates this Warning:

```
NDSolve::ibcinc: Warning: Boundary and initial conditions are inconsistent.
```

I understand that the boundary and initial conditions are inconsistent.
To solve this problem I looked through this webpage:

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html#1306392612

I noticed, however, that changing **j0** had no effect on the attained numerical solution and, in fact, leaving the symbol **j0** undefined does not lead NDSolve to complain about non-numerical derivatives and such.
This leads me to believe that NDSolve ignores somehow the boundary condition in the origin altogether, making it somewhat hard to debug the warning message about inconsistent boundary and initial conditions.

**To clarify my point about j0:**
I don't understand how NDSolve manages to ignore the boundary condition in the origin altogether without running into trouble. If I comment out the left b/c, NDSolve complains:

```
NDSolve::bcart: Warning: An insufficient number of boundary conditions have been specified for the direction of independent variable x. Artificial boundary effects may be present in the solution.
```

**Edit:**
One solution I found is to turn j0 into a Michaelis-Menten type of function of time.
Here, I also incorporate a valid point made in the comments: the Dirichlet b/c on the right of the domain was also inconsistent with the initial condition.

```
pde = D[u[x, t], t] == d*D[u[x, t], x, x] - \[Delta]*u[x, t]
bc = {D[u[x, t], x] == -((j0*t)/(1 + t)) /. x -> 0, u[x, t] == 0 /. x -> length}
ic = u[x, t] == u0 /. t -> 0
params = {d -> 100, \[Delta] -> 1, length -> 600, u0 -> 0, j0 -> 40}
tFinal = 150;
soln = NDSolve[Flatten@{pde, bc, ic} /. params, u, {t, 0, tFinal}, {x, 0, length /. params}, Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
  "MinPoints" -> 1000}}]
```

Your help and suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: When I comment out `j0` I still get the (correct) warning about inconsistent initial conditions. Also, the fact that `j0` is not defined does not matter since the other boundary condition and the initial condition are inconsistent (too).

Comment: Thank you @ruebenko and I understand what you're saying about the boundary condition at x==length. However, I don't understand how NDSolve manages to ignore the boundary condition in the origin altogether without running into trouble. If I comment out the left b/c, NDSolve complains:

      `NDSolve::bcart: Warning: An insufficient number of boundary conditions have been specified for the direction of independent variable x. Artificial boundary effects may be present in the solution.`

Comment: I am not sure I can follow you; the warning says there is an insufficient number of bcs. For the method of lines, you need an initial condition, and (in 2D) a boundary to the left and one to the right. Note that, for example, replacing the Dirichlet condition with `D[u[x, t], x] == -((j0*t)/(1 + t)) /. x -> length` also finds a solution. Does this help?

Comment: In the above comment I meant to say 1D (in space).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Boundary condition with spatial derivative is severely ignored by NDSolve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/123269/boundary-condition-with-spatial-derivative-is-severely-ignored-by-ndsolve)

Answer (score 2):

The solution has actually been implied on the page you linked. (Well, I admit that tutorial isn't that readable, I myself didn't notice the solution therein until recently.) To fix the problem, you need to add option `Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> {True, "ScaleFactor" -> 1}}` to `NDSolve`, because `NDSolve` will automatically set `"ScaleFactor" -> 0` for non-Dirichlet boundary condition, when i.c. and b.c. are inconsistent, this will make the non-Dirichlet inconsistent b.c. be severely ignored. (In your case since the right hand side of your Neumann condition `D[u[x, t], x] == -j0 /. x -> 0` isn't a function of `t`, it's completely ignored. ) For more information you can revisit the tutorial.

After adding the option, the solution is obviously influenced by `j0`:

```
pde = D[u[x, t], t] == d*D[u[x, t], x, x] - δ*u[x, t];
bc = {D[u[x, t], x] == -j0 /. x -> 0, u[x, t] == 0 /. x -> length};
ic = u[x, t] == u0 /. t -> 0;
params = {d -> 10, δ -> 1, length -> 600, u0 -> 200};
tFinal = 150;
solp = ParametricNDSolveValue[Flatten@{pde, bc, ic} /. params, 
  u, {t, 0, tFinal}, {x, 0, length /. params}, j0, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> {True, "ScaleFactor" -> 1}}]
Plot[solp[#][x, 100] & /@ Range[4] // Evaluate, {x, 0, length/10 /. params}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]