# Boundary condition with spatial derivative is ignored by NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, physics, finite-element-method

Consider the following differential equation:

$$\begin{align*}&\rho C_p\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}\right)=k\left[\frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x^2}\right]+\dot{q}\\
&\text{at }x=0,\;\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}=0\\
&\text{at }x=1,\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}=C_1(T(t,1)-C_2)\\
&\text{at }t=0,T(0,x)=C_3
\end{align*}$$

```
c1 = -10;
c2 = 10;
c3 = 20;    
q[t, x] = 100000;
    heat = 
 NDSolve[{1591920 D[u[t, x], t] == .87 D[u[t, x], x, x] + q[t, x], 
       (D[u[t, x], x] /. x -> 0) == 0, (D[u[t, x], x] /. x -> 1) == 
    c1 (u[t, 1] - c2), u[0, x] == c3}, u, {t, 0, 600}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

The solver doesn't work and gives the warning:

> NDSolve::ibcinc: Warning: boundary and initial conditions are inconsistent. >>

It is clear where the problem lies:

```
D[u[0, x], x] /. {x -> 1} /. heat
u[0.0, 1] - c2) /. heat
```

> {0.}
>
> {10.}

Causing `(D[u[t, x], x] /. x -> 1) == c1 (u[t, 1] - c2)` to evaluate as false

And rather than approach `c2`, the heat goes up:
Note that editing `c1` does affect the graph, while editing `c2` does not.

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[u[t, x] /. heat], {t, 0, 600}, {x, 0, 1}, 
PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"t(s)", "x(m)"}, 
ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]
```

[image: plot]

Why does this boundary directive refuse to be set, with the whole domain of `D[u[0, x], x]` returning `0`?

[Linked](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/122079/problem-with-convection-heat-transfer-boundary-condition/122089?noredirect=1#comment333236_122089)

Comment: I've rewritten my answer below, aiming at making it a canonical one, have a look. Any suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Changed the Derivative boundaries to [`NeumannValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NeumannValue.html) and FEA needed to be specified.

```
c1 = -10;
c2 = 10;
c3 = 20;
q[t_, x_] := 100000;

heat = NDSolveValue[{
   1591920 D[u[t, x], t] - ((87/100) D[u[t, x], x, x] + q[t, x]) == 
    NeumannValue[0, x == 0] + NeumannValue[c1 (u[t, x] - c2), x == 1],
   u[0, x] == c3},
  u, {t, 0, 600}, {x, 0, 1}, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines",  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
             "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> {"Length" -> 0.001}}}}]

Plot3D[Evaluate[heat[t, x]], {t, 0, 600}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All,
  AxesLabel -> {"t(s)", "x(m)"}, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]
```

[image]

**Update**

Adding appropriate units

```
rc = (8950) (385); (*density, Kg/m3 x heat capacity, J/Kg K*)
k = 385; (*thermal conductivity, W/m K*)

h = 10;(*heat transfer coefficient, W/m^2 K*)

ambT = 10; (*T, K*)
iniT = 20; (*T, K*)

q[t_, x_] := 0;  (*W/m^3*)

heat = NDSolveValue[{
   rc D[u[t, x], t] - (k D[u[t, x], x, x] + q[t, x]) == 
    NeumannValue[0, x == 0] + NeumannValue[-h (u[t, x] - ambT), x == 1],
   u[0, x] == iniT},
  u, {t, 0, 600}, {x, 0, 1}, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t, 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
      "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> {"Length" -> 0.001}}}}]

Plot3D[Evaluate[heat[t, x]], {t, 0, 600}, {x, 0, 1}, 
  PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"t(s)", "x(m)"}, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, ColorData["TemperatureMap"][z/40]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

`q = 0`: Looks correct with slight cooling to the ambient temperature of 10.

[image]

`q = 100000`: A convection coefficient of 10 can't dissipate this source so the temperature rises.

[image]

`q[t_, x_] := If[0 < t < 100, 100000, 0]`

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate[heat[t, x]], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 40}},
   PlotLabel -> t, AxesLabel -> {"x(m)", "T(K)"}, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, ColorData["TemperatureMap"][y/40]], 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False], {t, 0, 600}]
```

Reference my answer here: [Couple a PDE and ODE in NDSolve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/121979/couple-a-pde-and-ode-in-ndsolve/122101#122101)

Comment: Temp still seems to be increasing rather than decreasing when running `Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate[heat[t, x]], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
  AxesLabel -> {"t(s)", "x(m)"}, 
  ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"], {t, 0, 600}]`

Comment: However, the questioned problem does seem to be answered, it seems now a point around `x=0.95` is playing havoc.

Comment: @Feyre I added some updates that may help.

Comment: Excellent work. The initial values weren't mine and I suspected them part of the problem. If I could I'd accept again.

Answer (score 23):

### Short Answer

Set

```
Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
         "DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> {True, "ScaleFactor" -> 1}}
```

inside `NDSolve` will resolve the problem. It's not necessary to set `"ScaleFactor"` to `1`, it just needs to be a not-that-small positive number.

### Long Answer

The answer for this problem is hidden in [this obscure tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html#1306392612). I'll try my best to retell it in an easier-to-understand way.

Let's consider the following simpler initial-boundary value problem (IBVP) of heat equation that suffers from the same issue:

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$$
$$u(0,x)=x(1-x)$$
$$u(t,0)=0,\ \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\bigg|_{x=1}=0$$
$$t>0,\ 0\leq x\leq 1$$

Clearly $u(0,x)=x(1-x)$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\bigg|_{x=1}=0$ is inconsistent. When you solve it with `NDSolve` / `NDSolveValue`, `ibcinc` warning will be spit out:

```
tend = 1; xl = 0; xr = 1;

With[{u = u[t, x]},
 eq = D[u, t] == D[u, x, x];
 ic = u == (x - xl) (xr - x) /. t -> 0;
 bc = {u == 0 /. x -> xl, D[u, x] == 0 /. x -> xr};]

sol = NDSolveValue[{eq, ic, bc}, u, {t, 0, tend}, {x, xl, xr}]
```

> NDSolveValue::ibcinc

and further check shows the boundary condition (b.c.) $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\bigg|_{x=1}=0$ isn't satisfied at all:

```
Plot[D[sol[t, x], x] /. x -> xr // Evaluate, {t, 0, tend}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Why does this happen?

The best way for explaination is re-implementing the method used by `NDSolve` in this case i.e. *method of lines*, all by ourselves.

As mentioned in the document, method of lines is a numeric method that discretizes the partial diffential equation (PDE) in all but one dimension and then integrating the semi-discrete problem as a system of ordinary differential equations (ODEs) or differential algebraic equations (DAEs). Here I discretize the PDE with 2nd order centered difference formula:

$$f'' (x_i)\simeq\frac{f (x_{i}-h)-2 f (x_i)+f (x_{i}+h)}{h^2}$$

```
Clear@dx
formula = eq /. {D[u[t, x], t] -> u[x]'[t], 
   D[u[t, x], x, x] -> (u[x - dx][t] - 2 u[x][t] + u[x + dx][t])/dx^2}

points = 5;
dx = (xr - xl)/(points - 1);
ode = Table[formula, {x, xl + dx, xr - dx, dx}]
```

> ```
> {u[1/4]'[t] == 16 (u[0][t]   - 2 u[1/4][t] + u[1/2][t]), 
>  u[1/2]'[t] == 16 (u[1/4][t] - 2 u[1/2][t] + u[3/4][t]), 
>  u[3/4]'[t] == 16 (u[1/2][t] - 2 u[3/4][t] + u[1][t])}
> ```

I've chosen a very coarse grid for better illustration. The initial condition (i.c.) should also be discretized:

```
odeic = Table[ic /. u[t_, x_] :> u[x][t] // Evaluate, {x, xl, xr, dx}]
```

> ```
> {u[0][0] == 0, u[1/4][0] == 3/16, u[1/2][0] == 1/4, u[3/4][0] == 3/16, u[1][0] == 0}
> ```

We still need to deal with b.c.s. The Dirichlet b.c. doesn't need discretization:

```
bcnew1 = bc[[1]] /. u[t, x_] :> u[x][t]
```

> ```
> u[0][t] == 0
> ```

The Neumann b.c. contains the derivative of $x$ so we need to discretize it with the one-sided difference formula:

$$f' (x_n)\simeq \frac{f (x_{n}-2h)-4 f (x_{n}-h)+3 f (x_n)}{2 h}$$

```
bcnew2 = bc[[2]] /. 
  D[u[t, x_], x_] :> (u[x - 2 dx][t] - 4 u[x - dx][t] + 3 u[x][t])/(2 dx)
```

> ```
> 2 (u[1/2][t] - 4 u[3/4][t] + 3 u[1][t]) == 0
> ```

"OK, 5 unknowns, 5 equations, we can now solve the system with any *ODE* solver! Just *as `NDSolve` does*!" Sadly you were wrong if you thought this statement is correct, because:

1. Though `{ode, odeic, bcnew1, bcnew2}` is already a solvable system, it's not a set of ODEs, but **DAE**s. Notice here ODE refers to **explicit** ODE i.e. the coefficient of derivative term can't be $0$. Clearly, `bcnew1` and `bcnew2` don't **explicitly** contain the derivative of $t$.
2. Though `NDSolve` is able to handle the DAE system `{ode, odeic, bcnew1, bcnew2}` directly, it doesn't solve the PDE in this way by default. Instead, it'll try to transform the DAE system to an explicit ODE system, probably because its ODE solver is generally stronger than the DAE solver (at least now).

> **Remark**
>
> To be precise, internally `NDSolve` doesn't "transform the DAE system to an explicit ODE system", it directly discretize the PDE to an explicit ODE system that can be viewed as a transformation of `{ode, odeic, bcnew1, bcnew2}`, i.e. `{ode, odeic, bcnew1, bcnew2}` isn't really generated, but this truth doesn't influence the discussion in this answer.

So, how does `NDSolve` transform the DAE system to ODE system? "That's simple! Just eliminate some of the variables in `ode` and `odeic` with `bcnew1` and `bcnew2`! " Yeah this is a possible method, but not the one implemented in `NDSolve`. `NDSolve` has chosen a method that may be rather unusual at first glance. It mixes the original b.c. with its 1st order derivative respects to $t$. For our specific problem, the b.c. becomes:

```
odebc1 = D[#, t] + scalefactor1 # & /@ bcnew1
```

> ```
> scalefactor1 u[0][t] + u[0]'[t] == 0
> ```

```
odebc2 = D[#, t] + scalefactor2 # & /@ bcnew2
```

> ```
> 2 scalefactor2 (u[1/2][t] - 4 u[3/4][t] + 3 u[1][t]) + 
>    2 (u[1/2]'[t] - 4 u[3/4]'[t] + 3 u[1]'[t]) == 0
> ```

Where `scalefactor1` and `scalefactor2` are properly chosen coefficients.

It's not hard to notice this approach is systematic and easy to implement, and I guess that's the reason why `NDSolve` chooses it for transforming algebraic equations to ODEs. Nevertheless, this method has its disadvantage. The generated b.c. is equivalent to the original b.c., **only if the original b.c. is continuous and i.c. is consistent with the b.c.**.

Let's use `odebc1` as an example. In our case, `bc[[1]]` is continuous, and it's consistent with `ic`, so it can be easily rebuilt from `odebc1`:

```
DSolve[{odebc1, odeic[[1]]}, u[0][t], t]
```

> ```
> {{u[0][t] -> 0}}
> ```

However, if the i.c. is something that isn't consistent with `bc[[1]]`, for example `u[0][0] == 1`, the b.c. rebuilt from `odebc1` will become:

```
DSolve[{odebc1, u[0][0] == 1}, u[0][t], t]
```

> ```
> {{u[0][t] -> E^(-scalefactor1 t)}}
> ```

It's no longer equivalent to `bc[[1]]`, but when `scalefactor1` is a large positive number, this b.c. will converge to the original one.

Now here comes the key point. As stated in the document:

> With the default `"ScaleFactor"` value of `Automatic`, a scaling factor of
> `1` is used for Dirichlet boundary conditions and a scaling factor of `0`
> is used otherwise.

i.e. `scalefactor2` will be set to `0`. Guess what b.c. will be rebuilt in this way?:

```
With[{scalefactor2 = 0}, 
 DSolve[{D[#, t] + scalefactor2 # & /@ bc[[2]], D[ic, x] /. x -> xr}, 
  D[u[t, x], x] /. x -> xr, t]]
```

> ```
> {{Derivative[0, 1][u][t, 1] -> -1}}
> ```

It's a completely different b.c..

Back to the problem mentioned in the question, we can analyse its b.c. with the same method as above:

```
bcInQuestion = (D[u[t, x], x] /. x -> 1) == c1 (u[t, 1] - c2);
icInQuestion = u[0, x] == c3;
With[{sf = 0}, 
  DSolve[{D[#, t] + sf # & /@ bcInQuestion, D[icInQuestion, x] /. x -> 1}, 
   D[u[t, x], x] /. x -> 1, t]] /. u[0, _] :> c3
```

> ```
> {{Derivative[0, 1][u][t, 1] -> -c1 c3 + c1 u[t, 1]}}
> ```

We see `c1` is still in the rebuilt b.c., while `c2` is completely killed by the derivation, that's why OP found "editing `c1` does affect the graph, while editing `c2` does not".

OK, then why does `NDSolve` choose such a strange setting for scaling factor? The document explains as follows:

> There are two reasons that the scaling factor to multiply the original
> boundary condition is zero for boundary conditions with spatial
> derivatives. First, imposing the condition for the discretized
> equation is only a spatial approximation, so it does not always make
> sense to enforce it as exactly as possible for all time. Second,
> particularly with higher-order spatial derivatives, the large
> coefficients from one-sided finite differencing can be a potential
> source of instability when the condition is included. …

but **personally** I think this design is just too lazy: why not make `NDSolve` choose a non-zero scaling factor at least when `ibcinc` warning pops up and the order of spatial derivatives isn't too high (this is usually the case, the differential order of *most* of PDEs in practise is no higher than `2` )?

Anyway, now we know how to fix the issue. Just choose a positive scaling factor:

```
Clear[c2]
c1 = -10;
(*c2=10;*)
c3 = 20;
q[t, x] = 100000;
heat = ParametricNDSolveValue[{1591920 D[u[t, x], t] == .87 D[u[t, x], x, x] + 
      q[t, x], (D[u[t, x], x] /. x -> 0) == 0, (D[u[t, x], x] /. x -> 1) == 
     c1 (u[t, 1] - c2), u[0, x] == c3}, u, {t, 0, 600}, {x, 0, 1}, c2, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> {True, "ScaleFactor" -> 1}}];
Plot[heat[#][300, x] & /@ Range[10, 50, 10] // Evaluate, {x, 0.9, 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x(m)", "T"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now `c2` influences the solution.

Young has also [solved the problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/123271/1871) with the new-in-*v10* `"FiniteElement"` method, I guess it's probably because b.c.s are imposed in a completely different way when `"FiniteElement"` method is chosen, but I'd like not to talk too much about it given I'm still in *v9* and haven't looked into `"FiniteElement"`.

Comment: Thanks for the clear and in-depth explanation!

Comment: This problem persists in v11.3 at least, although `Plot[D[sol[t, x], x] /. x -> xr // Evaluate, {t, 0, tend}, PlotRange -> All]` gives a different _wrong_ curve

Comment: I have read this post once more. Btw, on the LHS of that three FD formulae, a prime is missing in each one.

Comment: please check your answer, where it states `{u[1/4][t] == ..., {u[1/2][t] ==, ... {u[3/4][t] ==...}`

Comment: @jsxs Oops, I see. Edited. Thx for pointing out. For such mistakes it's OK to directly edit the post without asking me :) .

Comment: @jsxs Code for transformation of `bc[[2]]` is already there, see the line below "i.e. `scalefactor2` will be set to `0`. Guess what b.c. will be rebuilt in this way?:"

Comment: yes, I see. Btw, I think it is better to mention in which case(s) when `Warning: boundary and initial conditions are inconsistent`  pops up, results given by NDSolve should be correct, we can just ignore the warning.

Comment: @jsxs That's a bit hard to summarize. For example, [this issue](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20729/1871) may involve in. Another possible issue is, "a scaling factor of 1 used for Dirichlet boundary conditions" can be improper if the interested time interval is rather short. So I'd like not to provide _rule of thumb_ for determing if an ibcinc warning is malignant, and let the readers judge it case by case. Once the reason why ibcinc pops up is understood, it should not be hard.