# Solving nonlinear diffusion equation by NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear, finite-difference-method

I have checked all issues regarding to solving nonlinear PDE numerically. I however try to solve following equation via NDSolve function and get some troubles.
 [image]

And this is my code for above-mentioned equations

```
rw = 0.05;
Sy = 0.15;
Kr = 0.0001*3600;
Q = 0.01;

sys = {Sy*Derivative[0, 1][h][r, t] == 
   Kr*h[r, t]*((Derivative[2, 0][h][r, t] + Derivative[1, 0][h][r, t]/
        r) + (Derivative[1, 0][h][r, t])^2),
  2*Pi*rw*Kr*h[rw, t]*Derivative[1, 0][h][rw, t] == -Q,
  h[100, t] == 0,
  h[r, 0] == 0.00001

  }; sol = 
 NDSolve[sys, {h}, {r, rw, 100}, {t, 0, 100000}, 
  Method -> "MethodOfLines"]
```

But the value evaluated by the numerical result is equal to it's initial condition and obviously wrong. Do I miss something in the code?

Comment: `h[100, t] == 0, h[r, 0] == 0.00001` tries to assign two different values to `h[100, 0]`. This needs to be fixed.  Also, `2*Pi*rw*Kr*h[rw, t]*Derivative[1, 0][h][rw, t] == -Q` is an unusual boundary condition, and I am uncertain how `NDSolve` will respond to it.

Comment: To be more specific, adding `Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
  "DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> {True, "ScaleFactor" -> 100}}` to `NDSolve` will fix your code. (You'll probably need `PlotRange->All` in `Plot3D`, too. )

Comment: I do not think that this question is a duplicate of the linked question (and especially not the answers contained there in)

Comment: @user21 Would you be willing to write an answer?

Comment: @halirutan  The comment by xzczd appears to give the correct answer.

Comment: @xzczd, do you want to post your comment as an answer?

Comment: @user21 Well, I can't remember clearly, but I think this post was "successfully" marked as duplicate of [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127411/1871)? If the solution in my comment above is correct, then I think our previous decision is right. How about marking it as duplicate again?