# Differences between DSolve and NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, warning-messages, physics

I have a question about the difference in the solution between `DSolve` and `NDSolve`.

I want to solve the Friedmann equation of

\begin{align}
3\left(\frac{\dot{a}^2}{a^2}+\frac{k}{a^2}\right)=8\pi G\rho(a)\,,
\end{align}

where $a(t)$ is the scale factor, $k=1,0,-1$, $G$ is Newton's gravitational constant, and $\rho$ is the energy density. For a Universe composed of radiation, I know that $\rho\sim a^{-4}$. For $k=1$ (and setting $G=1$), I can solve for $a(t)$ with Mathematica:

```
 DSolve[{3 (D[a[t], t]^2/a[t]^2 + 1/a[t]^2) == 8 Pi/a[t]^4, a[0] == 1}, a[t], t]
```

giving me a solution of:

```
{{a[t] -> Sqrt[3 - 2 Sqrt[3 (-3 + 8 \[Pi])] t - 3 t^2]/Sqrt[3]}, {a[t] -> Sqrt[3 + 2 Sqrt[3 (-3 + 8 \[Pi])] t - 3 t^2]/Sqrt[3]}}
```

Plotting the second solution, I get:

```
Plot[Sqrt[3 + 2 Sqrt[3 (-3 + 8 \[Pi])] t - 3 t^2]/Sqrt[2], {t, 0, 6}]
```

[image]

which is exactly what I want.

Now, solving the same equation with `NDSolve`:

```
sol = NDSolve[{3 (D[a[t], t]^2/a[t]^2 + 1/a[t]^2) == 8 Pi/a[t]^4, a[0] == 1}, a, {t, 0, 6}]
```

I get the following errors:

`NDSolve::ndsz: At t == 0.17823474500439837, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.`

`NDSolve::mxst: Maximum number of 799782 steps reached at the point t == 5.298557045191269.`

Plotting the solution, I get

```
Plot[Evaluate[a[t] /. sol[[2]]], {t, 0, 5.3}]
```

[image]

We see that the first half of the plot looks similar to the analytical solution, but then nothing is plotted. I decided to plot the real part of the solution and I found

[image]

while the imaginary part of the solution gave this plot:

[image]

Why are there differences between `DSolve` and `NDSolve`? I tried adding the solution

```
 Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> {True, "ScaleFactor" -> 1}}
```

as suggested [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/123269/boundary-condition-with-spatial-derivative-is-ignored-by-ndsolve/127411#127411), but it didn't fix the problem. I've also tried increasing `MaxSteps` to more than 100000 as well as changing the `WorkingPrecision`, `PrecisionGoal`, and `AccuracyGoal`. How do I make my numerical solution agree with my analytical solution?

Comment: But using `DSolve`, I get the error `DSolve::bvnul: For some branches of the general solution, the given boundary conditions lead to an empty solution.`, don't you get it? I suspect you must inspect the validity of your analytic function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both `NDSolve` and `DSolve` solve two equations:

```
Solve[{3 (D[a[t], t]^2/a[t]^2 + 1/a[t]^2) == 8 Pi/a[t]^4}, {a'[t]}]
(*
{{Derivative[1][a][t] -> -(Sqrt[8 π - 3 a[t]^2]/(Sqrt[3] a[t]))},
 {Derivative[1][a][t] -> Sqrt[8 π - 3 a[t]^2]/(Sqrt[3] a[t])}}
*)
```

The first message, `NDSolve::ndsz` is unimportant. It has to do with the solution to the first equation, which the OP ignores in both the `DSolve` and the `NDSolve` results.

The second comes up because `a[t]` approaches `8 π / 3` which causes the expression `8 π - 3 a[t]^2` under the radical to approximately vanish, perhaps even become negative due to numerical error at each discrete step.

A workaround is to differentiate the equation and choose for the additional initial condition, the value of the derivative `a'[0]` of the solution of interest.

```
Solve[{3 (D[a[t], t]^2/a[t]^2 + 1/a[t]^2) == 8 Pi/a[t]^4, a[t] == 1}, {a[t], a'[t]}]
(*
{{a[t] -> 1, Derivative[1][a][t] -> -Sqrt[1/3 (-3 + 8 π)]},
 {a[t] -> 1, Derivative[1][a][t] -> Sqrt[1/3 (-3 + 8 π)]}}
*)
```

The value for `a'[0]` is `Sqrt[1/3 (-3 + 8 π)]`.

```
sol = NDSolve[{D[3 (D[a[t], t]^2/a[t]^2 + 1/a[t]^2) == 8 Pi/a[t]^4, t],
    a[0] == 1, a'[0] == Sqrt[1/3 (-3 + 8 π)]}, a, {t, 0, 6}];
```

> NDSolve::ndsz: At t == 5.610575834501343`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.

```
ListLinePlot[a /. sol]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

*Addendum.*

I should probably have pointed out that `a[t] == 8 π / 3` is a singular solution:

```
3 (D[a[t], t]^2/a[t]^2 + 1/a[t]^2) == 8 Pi/a[t]^4 /. 
  a[t] -> Sqrt[8 Pi/3] // Simplify
(*  Derivative[1][a][t] == 0  *)
```

When the `NDSolve` integration reaches a time `t0` where `a[t0] == 8 π / 3`, there are two possible branches to follow. The one is shown in the `DSolve` solution (the same as mine above), and the other is the solution where `a[t] == 8 π / 3` for all `t > t0`, which is approximately the `NDSolve` solution in the OP (looking at the real and imaginary parts).