# Coupled PDE equation or boundary condition creating singularity issue

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, numerical-integration, boundary-conditions

Previous post: [Using NDSolve and PieceWise for boundary conditions for coupled PDEs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/213729/using-ndsolve-and-piecewise-for-boundary-conditions-for-coupled-pdes)

I realised that my previous post was a little vague so I hope this post clarifies any confusion. I've looked over the code much closer and I'm getting much closer to obtaining a solution. Currently the issue I face is I have 4 PDEs that I want to solve for using NDSolve:

```
pumpIntEqnF = -D[IPF[z, t], z] - (n/c) D[IPF[z, t], t] - 
  gP IPF[z, t] (IS1F[z, t] + IS1B[z,t]) - alphaP IPF[z, t]
pumpIntEqnB = D[IPB[z, t], z] - (n/c) D[IPB[z, t], t] - 
  gP IPB[z, t] (IS1F[z, t] + IS1B[z,t]) - alphaP IPB[z, t]
firStoEqnF = -D[IS1F[z, t], z] - (n/c) D[IS1F[z, t], t] + 
  gS1 IS1F[z, t] (IPF[z, t] + IPB[z, t]) - alphaS1 IS1F[z, t] + 
  sigmaSP (IPF[z, t] + IPB[z, t])
firStoEqnB = D[IS1B[z, t], z] - (n/c) D[IS1B[z, t], t] + 
  gS1 IS1B[z, t] (IPF[z, t] + IPB[z, t]) - alphaS1 IS1B[z, t] + 
  sigmaSP (IPF[z, t] + IPB[z, t])
```

However whenever I run the code to solve in NDSolve:

```
solIntEqn = 
 NDSolve[{pumpIntEqnF == 0, pumpIntEqnB == 0, firStoEqnF == 0, 
   firStoEqnB == 0,
   IPF[0, t] == PumpPeak*Exp[-0.5 ((t - toffset)/twidth)^2], 
   IPB[lR, t] == IPF[lR, t] ROCP, IS1F[0, t] == IS1B[0, t] RICS1, 
   IS1B[lR, t] == IS1F[lR, t] ROCS1,
   IPB[z, 0] == PumpPeak*Exp[-0.5 ((-toffset)/twidth)^2], 
   IPF[z, 0] == PumpPeak*Exp[-0.5 ((-toffset)/twidth)^2], 
   IS1F[z, 0] ==  0, IS1B[z, 0] ==  0},
  {IPF, IPB, IS1F, IS1B}, {t, 0, 20}, {z, 0, lR}, 
  MaxSteps -> Infinity, PrecisionGoal -> 2, AccuracyGoal -> 50, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
      "MinPoints" -> ppR, "MaxPoints" -> ppR, "DifferenceOrder" -> 2},
     Method -> {"Adams", "MaxDifferenceOrder" -> 1}}]
```

I get the error:

**NDSolve::ndsz: At t == 1.7666146472527202`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.**

My question is how can I resolve this issue?

Parameters:

```
ROCP = 1;
RICP = 0;
ROCS1 = 0.5;
RICS1 = 1;
L = 5 10^-2;
n = 1.556;
c = 30;
lR = 3;
R1 = 0.99;

gP = 20;
gS1 = 20;
sigmaSP = 10^-13;

toffset = 10;
twidth = 10;
Energy = 1.3 10^-4;
rad = 0.015;
PumpInt = ((Energy)/(twidth))/(Pi rad^2) ;
PumpPeak = Exp[0.5 ((-toffset)/(twidth))^2] PumpInt;

lc = n lR;
alphaP = 0 L/(2 lc)
alphaS1 = 0 (L - Log[R1])/(2 lc)

tmax = 20;
ppR = 90;
```

### My attempts at resolving the issue

After a lot of attempts at resolving this issue, I discovered that changing the boundary condition:

```
IS1F[0, t] == IS1B[0, t] RICS1
```

to:

```
IS1F[0, t] == 0
```

I obtain what I think is the correct solution:
[image: Looks to be correct for IPF and IPB]

[image: Looks to be correct for IS1F and IS1B]

But the boundary condition that I replace is important because it means that IS1F is generated when IS1B hits the starting "wall."

Furthermore, I have looked closely into my problem and have discovered that omitting the fourth PDE and setting IS1B[z,t] = 0 (i.e only solving for IPF, IPB, and IS1F) gives me a reasonable answer, which strongly suggests that IS1B[z,t] is causing the issue.

### Attempts at resolving the issue pt. 2:

By trying to incorporate the boundary condition that I want, I've discovered that changing the method in NDSolve to:

```
Method -> "LinearlyImplicitEuler", MaxSteps -> Infinity, AccuracyGoal -> 10
```

gets rid of the singularity error, but the graphs produced for IPB[z,t], IS1F[z,t], and IS1B[z,t] are clearly wrong:

```
Manipulate[Plot[{IPB[z, t] /. solIntEqn}, {t, 0, tmax}], {z, 0, lR}]
```

[image: Error for IPB]

```
Manipulate[Plot[{IS1F[z, t] /. solIntEqn}, {t, 0, tmax}], {z, 0, lR}]
```

[image: Error for IS1F]

```
Manipulate[Plot[{IS1B[z, t] /. solIntEqn}, {t, 0, tmax}], {z, 0, lR}]
```

[image: Error for IS1B]

So I think that the issue is related to the accuracy of the numerical method used, but I'm unsure on how to proceed.

### Update 16/02/2020

I think the error is to do with the boundary conditions, but I'm stuck on how to proceed. The PDEs are rate equations and the boundary and initial conditions are:

```
IPF[0, t] == PumpPeak*Exp[-0.5 ((t - toffset)/twidth)^2]
```

This is gaussian pump power being pumped into the 'cavity' at the input, z = 0, and is a function of time, t, and is travelling forward (to the right in positive z direction).

```
IPB[lR, t] == IPF[lR, t] ROCP
```

This is the backwards travelling wave (travels towards z = 0) and should be equal in amplitude to IPF[lR, t] since ROCP = 1, i.e IPF[lR, t] is being transferred into the backwards (travelling left in negative z direction) travelling wave IPB[lR, t]

```
IS1F[0, t] == IS1B[0, t] RICS1
```

This is the forward travelling first-stokes wave (IS1F) being generated from the backwards travelling first-stokes wave (IS1B) at z = 0. That is, IS1B is transforming into IS1F.

```
IS1B[lR, t] == IS1F[lR, t] ROCS1
```

Power is leaking out of the system (ROCS1 = 0.5), and IS1F is being transferred into the backwards travelling first-stokes wave (IS1B). So I should be losing power in the system.

```
IPB[z, 0] == PumpPeak*Exp[-0.5 ((-toffset)/twidth)^2] 
IPF[z, 0] == PumpPeak*Exp[-0.5 ((-toffset)/twidth)^2] 
IS1F[z, 0] ==  0, IS1B[z, 0] ==  0
```

These are the initial conditions.

I'm super lost on how to modify the boundary conditions whilst keeping the physics the same. All help is appreciated

### Units 6/04/2020

RICP, ROCP, RICS1, ROCS1: reflectivities of input and output couplers, unitless

L:Round-trip dissipative loss inside resonator, unitless

n: refractive index of diamond, unitless

c: speed of light, cm/ns

lR: length of cavity, cm

R1: loss term, unitless

gP: Raman gain for pump, (cm*ns)/J

gS1: Raman gain for first stokes, (cm*ns)/J

sigmaSP: Spontaneous Raman loss rate (taken from different paper), cm^-1

toffset: Offset of Gaussian peak from origin, ns

twidth: Width of Gaussian at full-width, half-max, ns

Energy: Energy of pump pulse, J

rad: Radius of beam, cm

PumpInt: Intensity of pump, J/(ns*cm^2)

PumpPeak: PumpPeak coefficient (ensure we start of with pump energy), J/(ns*cm^2)

lc: Optical length of Raman laser, cm

alphaP: Dissipative loss of extracavity Raman laser, cm^-1

alphaS1: Dissipative loss of extracavity Raman laser, cm^-1

tmax: Duration of process, ns

Comment: Rule of thumb: the initial value problem (IVP) solver of `NDSolve` is quite robust, if you're fighting with options about IVP solver, then you're probably on the wrong way.

Comment: Are you suggesting I have another look at variables, the PDEs, and boundary conditions? Cheers for the reply!

Comment: Yes, the IVP solver should be the last thing to check.

Comment: Just tried manually discretizing the system but the singularity is still there, so there's something wrong with the underlying model, I suspect. Adding some background information might help. Where does this PDE system come from? Is it from any literature, or you deduced it yourself?

Comment: Hi, these equations and conditions are based on the paper: “Numerical optimisation of the extracavity Raman laser with barium nitrate crystal”. The equations are 14a and 14b with conditions 15a, 15b, and 15c. Source: http://lib.fibopt.ru/Articles/PAPER/GPI/v267%20p480-486.pdf

Comment: Sorry I didn’t link the literature initially. I’ve been quite busy so it’s been quite a while since I’ve taken a look at my problem. I tried discretising the system in python and was still getting a singularity.

Comment: Have you checked if parameters are correct? Seems that you're not using SI units, if so, it can easily lead to mistake. Also, are you sure the equation system can be simplified in this way?

Comment: Hi, I've added the corresponding units and couldn't find anything wrong with them. I've also taken sigmaSP from a different paper, but using sigmaSP from this paper doesn't work either. The energy and beam radius were also given to me. One thing that I've noticed is that when I set IS1B to zero, and get rid of the fourth equation, everything works perfectly. But I need to account for IS1B. Sorry if this doesn't help out. Cheers.

Comment: "PumpInt: Intensity of pump, J/ns\*cm^2" J/ns\*cm^2 or J/(ns\*cm^2) ?

Comment: Sorry, the second one. I didn’t add parentheses but will fix that now.

Comment: Have you tried reproducing the result in the paper?

Comment: I haven’t tried deriving the results. I took the equations as being correct since they can be seen in other papers as well. I can try reproducing them though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106368/discussion-between-xzczd-and-ibis-prod1gy).