# How to set MaxStepSize for the case of two variables

Tags: differential-equations, options, undocumented

The  option `MaxStepSize` permits to manually set the step size of the integration in `NDSolve` and similar functions.

How do I set its value in the case there are two variables with wildly different ranges?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try option `, MaxStepSize -> {.1, .01}`

Comment: Several examples making use of this syntax: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/229184/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/189770/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/218835/1871