# Inconsistent Boundary Conditions on Transient Heat Equation Partial Differential Equation

Tags: differential-equations, heat-equation

I am attempting to solve the equation

[image]

with the Wolfram one-liner

```
NDSolve[{D[ρ[y, t]] == D[D[ρ[y, t], y], y], ρ[-1, t] == 10, ρ[1, t] == 10,ρ[y, 0] == 0}, 
        ρ, {y, -1, 1}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

However, this threw a `NDSolve::ibcinc` warning that the initial and boundary conditions conflicted, as I didn't properly implement the inequalities on the initial and boundary conditions. How could I specify the inequalities on "t" properly to return a physical solution? I have searched through the Mathematica Stack Exchange to no avail for this issue.

Comment: Use damping as `[Rho][-1, t] == 10 (1-Exp[-10 t]), [Rho][1, t] == 10 (1-Exp[-10 t])`

Comment: Version 12.1 has a tutorial on [Heat Transfer Modeling](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/HeatTransfer/HeatTransfer.html)

Comment: First of all, the `D[\[Rho][y, t]]` should be `D[\[Rho][y, t],t]`. Then, "I have searched through the Mathematica Stack Exchange to no avail for this issue." you should have searched harder. Strongly related, if not duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127411/1871 To be more specific, add e.g. `Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
  "DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> {True, "ScaleFactor" -> 100}}` to `NDSolve`.

Answer (score 4):

This can be solved analytically. Using V 12.1

```
ClearAll[y, t, u]
pde = D[u[y, t], t] == D[u[y, t], {y, 2}];
ic = u[y, 0] == 0;
bc = {u[-1, t] == 10, u[1, t] == 10};
sol = DSolve[{pde, ic, bc}, u[y, t], {y, t}];
sol = sol /. K[1] -> n;
```

$$
\left\{\left\{u(y,t)\to 10-\frac{2 \underset{n=1}{\overset{\infty }{\sum }}\frac{\left(10-10 (-1)^n\right) e^{-\frac{1}{4} n^2 \pi ^2 t} \sin
   \left(\frac{1}{2} n \pi  (y+1)\right)}{n}}{\pi }\right\}\right\}
$$

[image]

```
sol = sol /. Infinity -> 10; (*more than enough terms*)
Manipulate[
 Quiet@Plot[Activate@Evaluate[(u[y, t] /. sol) /. t -> t0], {y, -1, 1},
   PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-0.5, 11}},
   GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, 
   PlotStyle -> Red,
   AxesLabel -> {"space", "solution u"},
   BaseStyle -> 12
   ],
 {{t0, 0.01, "time"}, 0.01, 5, .01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {t0}
 ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the square-brackets!

Try

```
rho=NDSolveValue[{Derivative[0, 1][Rho][y, t] ==Derivative[2, 0][Rho][y, t] 
, Rho [-1, t] == 10, Rho [1, t] == 10,Rho [y, 0] == 0}, Rho , {y, -1, 1}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

which evaluates with an errormessage "NDSolveValue::ibcinc: Warning: boundary and initial conditions are inconsistent.".

```
Plot3D[rho[y, t], {y, -1, 1}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

With `Rho [-1, t] == 10 (1 - Exp[-10 t]), Rho [1, t] == 10 (1 - Exp[-10 t])` (Thanks @AlexTrounev )  error message disappears!

```
rho1 = NDSolveValue[{Derivative[0, 1][Rho][y, t] ==Derivative[2, 0][Rho][y, t] 
, Rho [-1, t] == 10 (1 - Exp[-10 t]),Rho [1, t] == 10 (1 - Exp[-10 t]), Rho [y, 0] ==0},Rho , {y, -1, 1}, {t, 0, 10}]
Plot3D[rho1[y, t], {y, -1, 1}, {t, 0,10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: The solution doesn't satisfy the Rho[-1,t], Rho[1,t] = 10, is this solvable?

Comment: Change the boundary conditions as @AlexTrounev suggested.

Answer (score 2):

In order to satisfy boundary conditions, change initial condition to `\[Rho][y, 0] == 10 UnitStep[Abs[y] - 1]` .

```
ndsol2 = NDSolve[{D[\[Rho][y, t], t] == 
  D[\[Rho][y, t], y, y], \[Rho][-1, t] == 10, \[Rho][1, t] == 
10, \[Rho][y, 0] == 10 UnitStep[Abs[y] - 1]}, \[Rho], 
{y, -1, 1}, {t, 0, 10}, MaxStepSize -> 0.001, MaxSteps -> 10^5, 
StartingStepSize -> 0.0002]

Plot3D[\[Rho][y, t] /. ndsol2[[1]], {y, -1, 1}, {t, 0, 2}, 
   PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Test for error in diffequation and initial condition.

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[
  D[\[Rho][y, t], t] - D[\[Rho][y, t], y, y] /. ndsol2[[1]]], 
  {y, -1, 1}, {t, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> 10^-4]

Plot[Evaluate[\[Rho][y, 0] - 10 UnitStep[Abs[y] - 1] /. 
  ndsol2[[1]]], {y, .99, 1}, 
PlotRange -> 15, GridLines -> Automatic]
```