# Looking for intuition as to what numerical issue makes this solution of NDSolve blow up unphysically

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, finite-element-method

I am solving the spherically symmetric wave equation in 3 dimensions on $r\in[0,2\pi]$
$$(\partial_t^2 - \frac{1}{r^2} \partial_r r^2 \partial_r) \theta(t,r)=0$$
with initial conditions $\theta(0,r)=e^{-(r-3)^2}$ and $\partial_t\theta(0,r)=0 $, imposing boundary conditions
$$\partial_r\theta(t,0)=0, \qquad \partial_t(r\theta)(t,6)+\partial_r(6\theta)(t,6)=0.$$
The first is necessary for smoothness at the origin and the second  (necessary to solve on a finite domain) should make sure that no information comes form outside the domain.

I include my code below. As you will see, the solution behaves reasonable at first and then starts growing for no reason. I would like to gain some intuition as to what numerically is the problem and how to extend the reasonable behaviour time.

```
tend = 100.;
rstart = 1/10^100;
rend = 6;

eq = D[θ[t, r], {t, 2}] - 1/r^2 D[r^2 D[θ[t, r], r], r] == 0;
ic = {θ[0, r] == Exp[-(r - 3)^2], (D[θ[t, r], t] /. t -> 0) == 0};
bc = {(D[θ[t, r], r] /. r -> rstart) == 
0, (D[r θ[t, r], t] /. r -> rend) + (D[r θ[t, r], r] /. r -> rend) == 0};

sol = NDSolve[Flatten@{eq, ic, bc}, θ, {t, 0, tend}, {r, rstart, rend}]
Animate[Plot[{θ[t, r] /. sol}, {r, rstart, rend}, PlotRange -> {{rstart, rend}, {-2, 2}}], {t, 0, tend}]
```

Edit: I'm running version 12.1. Below I include an snapshot of the animation when the solution starts to drift downwards

[image]

Comment: Does `“DifferenceOrder” -> “Pseudospectral”` in the spatial discretization help?

Comment: “As you will see, the solution behaves reasonable at first and then starts growing for no reason.” I don't seem to see it in _v12.3.1_, can you add your version info and a picture showing  the growing?

Comment: @xzczd I've added a picture of a timeslice when the solutions starts to go off. My version is 12.1. I hope that helps

Comment: Here's the result of v12.3.1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8STbu.png What if you add `Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> 45, "MinPoints" -> 45, 
    "DifferenceOrder" -> 4}, Method -> "Adams"}` to `NDSolve` in _v12.1_? Also, you may need `"DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> {True, "ScaleFactor" -> 100}`. (To learn more about this option, you can read the following post: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127411/1871 )

Comment: Just tested in _v9.0.1_, I observed similar phenomenon, and the option combination in my last comment fixes the problem in _v9.0.1_. A simpler solution is to add `MaxStepSize -> {0.05, Automatic}`. Do these options work in _v12.1_?

Comment: @xzczd adding MaxStepSize -> {0.05, Automatic} prolonged the reasonable behaviour but eventually, around t=500 it goes off again. Your previous suggestion, *including the "DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> {True, "ScaleFactor" -> 100} option* works great! without the last option it also eventually goes off

Answer (score 4):

`MethodOfLines` with `FiniteElement` gives a more plausible solution:

`bc` is changed to `NeumannValue` (first bc is automatically fullfilled)

```
teta = NDSolveValue [Flatten@{-((2 r \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Theta]\), TagBox[RowBox[{"(",RowBox[{"0", ",", "1"}], ")"}],Derivative],MultilineFunction->None]\)[t, r] +r^2\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Theta]\),TagBox[RowBox[{"(",RowBox[{"0", ",", "2"}], ")"}],Derivative],MultilineFunction->None]\)[t, r])/r^2) +\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Theta]\),TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"2", ",", "0"}], ")"}],Derivative],MultilineFunction->None]\)[t, r] ==NeumannValue[-Derivative[1, 0][\[Theta]][t, r], r== 6] , ic }, 
\[Theta], {t, 0, tend}, {r, rstart, rend},Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t,"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement" ,"MeshOptions" -> { "MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.1} }}]

Plot3D[teta[t, r], {t, 0, tend/5}, {r, rstart,rend}, PlotPoints -> 100, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

OK, since OP confirms the following solution also works in *v12.1*, let me turn it into an answer: I observe similar behavior in *v9.0.1*, and adding

```
Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> 45, "MinPoints" -> 45,
                              "DifferenceOrder" -> 4}, 
  "DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> {True, "ScaleFactor" -> 100}, Method -> "Adams"}
```

is a way to resolve the problem. To understand why `DifferentiateBoundaryConditions` is added, you can read [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127411/1871).

Answer (score 3):

Putting [my comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/262182/looking-for-intuition-as-to-what-numerical-issue-makes-this-solution-of-ndsolve#comment652741_262182) into an answer: `"DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"` seems to work.

```
sol = NDSolve[
  Flatten@{eq, ic, bc}, θ, {t, 0, tend}, {r, rstart, rend}, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
      "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"}}]

Plot3D[θ[t, r] /. sol, {t, 0, tend/5}, {r, rstart, rend}, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

It throws a warning:

> NDSolve::ibcinc: Warning: boundary and initial conditions are inconsistent.