# "NDSolve: boundary and initial conditions are inconsistent"?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

```
r = 0.04;
v1 = 0.25;
v2 = 0.1;
sigma = Sqrt[v1 + v2];
NDSolve[{D[f[t, x], t] + 0.5 (v1 + v2) x^2 D[D[f[t, x], x], x] - 
    r f[t, x] + r x D[f[t, x], x] == 0, f[t, 0.] == Exp[-r (1. - t)], 
  f[t, 1.] - Derivative[0, 1][f][t, 1.] == 0., 
  f[1., x] == 1. - x}, f, {t, 0., 1.}, {x, 0., 1.}]


u[t_, x_] := 
  N[(1 + (sigma^2)/(2*r)) x CDF[
      NormalDistribution[], (1/(sigma*Sqrt[(1 - t)]))*(Log[
          x] + (r + 0.5*sigma^2)*(1 - t))] + 
    Exp[-r*(1 - t)]*
     CDF[NormalDistribution[], -(1/(sigma*Sqrt[(1 - t)]))*(Log[
          x] + (r - 0.5*sigma^2)*(1 - t))] + (-sigma^2/(2*r))*
     Exp[-r*(1 - t)]*x^(1 - 2*r/(sigma^2))*
     CDF[NormalDistribution[], -(1/(sigma*Sqrt[(1 - t)]))*(Log[
          1/x] + (r - 0.5*sigma^2)*(1 - t))] - x];
```

I am verifying the theoretical solution u of f, and I am getting the error message "NDSolve: boundary and initial conditions are inconsistent". Why is this happening?

Comment: As mentioned in the message, "NDSolve: boundary and initial conditions are inconsistent." The inconsistency can be easily verified by `solf[1, x_] := 1. - x;
f[t, 1.] - Derivative[0, 1][f][t, 1.] == 0. /. t -> 1 /. f -> solf`. Please read the document for the warning message carefully for more info.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I found that there is a problem with my boundaries. This is about the PDE for lookback option pricing, where the boundary condition is: f[t, 1.] - Derivative[0, 1][f][t, 1.] == 0. The range of t in this equation is [0,1). Could you please advise me on how to modify the code to restrict the range of t to [0,1)?

Comment: “solf[1, x_] := 1. - x; f[t, 1.] - Derivative[0, 1][f][t, 1.] == 0. /. t -> 1 /. f -> solf. ” I can not understand, this is  modify the code to restrict the range of t to [0,1)?

Comment: The code in my last comment is for showing you the i.c. and b.c. is indeed inconsistent. As to how to fix the problem you're facing, the easiest solution is `Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> False}`. As to why this works, read this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127411/1871

Comment: Ok,Thank you very much. According to your code, I have successfully generated the function plot.

Answer (score 7):

> Why is this happening?

You say that `f[1,x]==1-x` which means at time `t=1` and for any `x`, then `f=1-x`. Lets take x=1 for example. This means  at time `t=1` then `f` must zero when `x=1`.

Next you say `f[t,1]==(D[f[t,x],x]/.x->1)`  But `f[1,x]==1-x`. Taking derivative w.r.t. x gives `-1`. Which means `f[t,1]=-1`

So we have `f=-1` at time `t=1` when `x=1`

and

we also have `f=0` at time `t=1` when `x=1`.

This is inconsistent.