Finite difference method in 2D
We look for $u(x, y, t)$ satisfying
$$
 \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\lambda_1 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+\lambda_2 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}+\mu u(1-u), \quad t>0, \quad(x, y) \in \Omega$$
$$
u(x, y, 0)=u^0(x, y), \quad 0 \leq u^0 \leq 1, \quad(x, y) \in \Omega_0 \subset \Omega, 
u=0, \quad t>0, \quad(x, y) \in \partial \Omega$$
where $\Omega=\{(x, y):|x|<a,|y|<b\}, \partial \Omega=\{(x, y):|x|=a or |y|=b\}$, $\Omega_0$ is a local subset of $\Omega$.
Here the following finite difference scheme (in 2D)
$\Omega$ is divided into a regular, rectangular grid with node points $\left(x_n, y_m\right)$
$$x_n=-a+(n-1) h,  n=1,2, \ldots, N$$
$$y_m=-b+(m-1) k,  m=1,2, \ldots, M$$
where $h=(2 a) /(N-1)$ and $k=(2 b) /(M-1)$.
Writing $t_p=p \tau, p=1,2, \ldots$, where $\tau>0$ is the time step, we can then discretize $u(x, y, t)$ into
$u_{n m}^p=u\left(x_n, y_m, t_p\right)$.
$u_{n, m}^{p+1}=u_{n, m}^p+\tau{\frac{\lambda_1}{h^2}[u_{n+1, m}^p-2 u_{n, m}^p+u_{n-1, m}^p]+\frac{\lambda_2}{k^2}[u_{n, m+1}^p-2 u_{n, m}^p+u_{n, m-1}^p]
+\mu u_{n, m}^p(1-u_{n, m}^p)}$\
$n=2, \ldots, N-1 \quad m=2, \ldots, M-1$
For the boundary condition, we should use
$$u_{1, m}^{p+1}=u_{N, m}^{p+1}=0,  m=1,2, \ldots, M$$
$$u_{n, 1}^{p+1}=u_{n, M}^{p+1}=0,  n=1,2, \ldots, N$$
$\Omega$ is divided into a regular, rectangular grid with node points $\left(x_n, y_m\right)$
$$x_n=-a+(n-1) h,  n=1,2, \ldots, N$$
$$y_m=-b+(m-1) k,  m=1,2, \ldots, M$$
So I want to code that in Mathematica to get Contour plots for long term $u$ at various times to observe traveling waves and also to calculate its speed, but it doesn't work. Note that in this code I assume all constants are equal to 1 and I just try to visualize the solution in this code.
(* Define constants *)
a = 1; b = 1; N = 100; M = 100; lambda1 = 0.1; lambda2 = 0.1; mu = 0.1; tau = 0.01;

(* Define grid *)
h = (2*a)/(N-1); k = (2*b)/(M-1);
x = Table[-a + (n-1)*h, {n, 1, N}];
y = Table[-b + (m-1)*k, {m, 1, M}];

(* Define initial condition *)
u0[x_, y_] := (1 + Exp[(x - y/Sqrt[2])/Sqrt[6]])^(-2);
uInit = Table[u0[x[[n]], y[[m]]], {n, 1, N}, {m, 1, M}];

(* Initialize solution array *)
u = Table[0, {p, 0, 100}, {n, 1, N}, {m, 1, M}];
u[[0]] = uInit;

(* Finite difference scheme *)
Do[
  Do[
    Do[
      If[2 <= n <= N-1 && 2 <= m <= M-1,
        u[[p+1, n, m]] = u[[p, n, m]] + 
          tau*(lambda1/h^2)*(u[[p, n+1, m]] - 2*u[[p, n, m]] + u[[p, n-1, m]]) + 
          tau*(lambda2/k^2)*(u[[p, n, m+1]] - 2*u[[p, n, m]] + u[[p, n, m-1]]) + 
          tau*mu*u[[p, n, m]]*(1 - u[[p, n, m]])
      ];
      If[n == 1 || n == N, u[[p+1, n, m]] = 0];
      If[m == 1 || m == M, u[[p+1, n, m]] = 0]
    , {m, 1, M}]
  , {n, 1, N}]
, {p, 0, 99}];

(* Visualize solution *)
ListPlot3D[u[[100]], PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "u"}]


Please include in your question the code you have tried and the difficulties you encountered.

@bbgodfrey , i use a c python code but it doesnt work , i will add it in my question

This website is for Mathematica code only.  Please show the Mathematica code you have tried.

@bbgodfrey see my edit please ,

Readers much prefer that the code be provided in a form that can be copied from the question and plugged into Mathematica.  An image of the code is not sufficient.

@bbgodfrey see my edit please , im not familiar with coding in mathematica and even numerical analysis ido mainly fundamental and analytical things


Since you're using Mathematica, why not use NDSolve/NDSolveValue to solve the PDE? 2. Your code does provide a solution, what do you mean by "doesn't work"? Please clarify. 3. Why do you translate the right hand side of difference equation to ListCorrelate[{{0, 1, 0}, {1, -4, 1}, {0, 1, 0}}, u, {2, 2}, 0]? Where's the $u(1-u)$ term?



Notice the line Monitor[Do[If[Mod[step, 50] == 0, AppendTo[solutionAtTimeSteps, u]], {step, nSteps}], step] doesn't make sense, because the us at intermediate time steps are simply not recorded by your previous code.


@xczd my aim is to use finite diffrence sheme in 2D

Another problem is the use of capital N as a variable: it is a reserved symbol in Mathematica.

@mattiav27 thank you i changed to K but still havent get the result i want


Always pay attention to the color of variable, when it's empty, usually it's blue. Otherwise, it's usually black. Those built-in functions that beginners will get in touch with are all black. 2. Index of list in Mathematica starts from 1, not 0. 3. Mathematica is a dynamic language, don't use it like C etc., you should write the code line by line to make sure every line of code is correct. (For example, by executing N=100, you'll immediately see it's wrong. )


@xzczd Could you show solution computed with NDSolve with initial and boundary condition  u[x, y, 0] == (1 +      Exp[(x - y/Sqrt[2])/Sqrt[6]])^(-2), DirichletCondition[  u[x, y, t] == 0, True] ? :)

@alex You've encountered this issue: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127411/1871 :)

@xzczd Thank you. Nevertheless please check that  sol1 generated without any messages. :)

@AlexTrounev It's the same issue, adding "DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> {True, "ScaleFactor" -> 100} will fix it. (I'd argue the missing of warning message is actually a bug. )

The answer in not simple even question looks like very simple. First, it seems that we can't compute solution with NDSolve since this code with sol1, sol2 generates wrong answer due to boundary conditions,
 sol1 = NDSolveValue[{D[u[x, y, t], t] == 
      lambda1  D[u[x, y, t], x, x] + lambda2  D[u[x, y, t], y, y] + 
       mu  u[x, y, t] (1 - u[x, y, t]) /. {lambda1 -> 0.1, 
      lambda2 -> 0.1, mu -> 0.1}, 
    u[x, y, 0] == (1 + Exp[(x - y/Sqrt[2])/Sqrt[6]])^(-2), 
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y, t] == 0, True]}, u, {t, 0, 1}, 
   Element[{x, y}, Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}]], 
   Method -> {"TimeIntegration" -> {"IDA", "MaxDifferenceOrder" -> 2},
      "PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
       "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement"}}}]; // \
AbsoluteTiming

sol2 = NDSolveValue[{D[u[x, y, t], t] == 
     lambda1  D[u[x, y, t], x, x] + lambda2  D[u[x, y, t], y, y] + 
      mu  u[x, y, t] (1 - u[x, y, t]) /. {lambda1 -> 0.1, 
     lambda2 -> 0.1, mu -> 0.1}, 
   u[x, y, 0] == (1 + Exp[(x - y/Sqrt[2])/Sqrt[6]])^(-2), 
   u[-1, y, t] == 0, u[1, y, t] == 0, u[x, -1, t] == 0, 
   u[x, 1, t] == 0}, u, {t, 0, 1}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
      "MaxPoints" -> 81, "MinPoints" -> 41, "DifferenceOrder" -> 2}}]

It is why we try my favorite linear FEM as follows
lambda1 = 0.1; lambda2 = 0.1; mu = 0.1; tau = 1/300; 
U[0][x_, y_] := (1 + Exp[(x - y/Sqrt[2])/Sqrt[6]])^(-2); 
Do[U[i] = 
    NDSolveValue[{(u[x, y] - U[i - 1][x, y])/tau == 
       lambda1  D[u[x, y], x, x] + lambda2  D[u[x, y], y, y] + 
        mu  u[x, y] (1 - U[i - 1][x, y]), 
      DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]}, u, 
     Element[{x, y}, Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}]], 
     Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
       "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01}}];, {i, 1, 
   300}] // AbsoluteTiming 

It takes about 23.3433 s on my laptop. With this solution we have mesh as follows
mesh = U[1]["ElementMesh"]

Out[]= NDSolve`FEM`ElementMesh[{{-1., 1.}, {-1., 
   1.}}, {NDSolve`FEM`QuadElement["<" 400 ">"]}]

Visualization
Table[Plot3D[U[i][x, y], Element[{x, y}, mesh], 
  PlotLabel -> Row[{"t =", N[i/300]}], PlotTheme -> "Marketing", 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", MeshStyle -> White], {i, 50, 300, 50}]


Now we can try FDM code taken from here with small modification
XYgrid[dom_List, pts_List] := 
  MapThread[
   N@Range[Sequence @@ #1, Abs[Subtract @@ #1]/#2] &, {dom, 
    pts - 1}];
BoundaryIndex[xgridlen_, ygridlen_] := 
  Module[{tmp, left, right, bot, top, left1, right1}, 
   tmp = Table[(n - 1) ygridlen + Range[1, ygridlen], {n, 1, 
      xgridlen}]; {left, right} = tmp[[{1, -1}]]; {left1, right1} = 
    tmp[[{2, -2}]]; {bot, top} = 
    Transpose[{First[#], Last[#]} & /@ tmp]; {top, right[[2 ;; -2]], 
    bot, left[[2 ;; -2]], right1[[2 ;; -2]], left1[[2 ;; -2]]}];

FDMat[deriv_, xygrid_, difforder_] := 
 Map[NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[#, xygrid, 
     "DifferenceOrder" -> difforder]["DifferentiationMatrix"] &, deriv]



fdmsol[lambda1_, lambda2_, mu_] := 
  Module[{dt = 1/300, tmax = 302, domain = {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
    pts = {21, 21}, difforder = 4}, 
   xygrid = XYgrid[domain, pts]; {nx, ny} = 
    Map[Length, xygrid]; {top, right, bot, left, right1, left1} = 
    BoundaryIndex[nx, ny]; {dx2, dy2} = 
    FDMat[{{2, 0}, {0, 2}}, xygrid, difforder]; 
   uvar0 = ConstantArray[0, {nx ny, tmax}]; 
   boundaries = Join[top, right, bot, left]; 
   sgrid = Flatten[Outer[List, Sequence @@ xygrid], 1]; 
   matdt1 = IdentityMatrix[nx ny] - dt (lambda1 dx2 + lambda2 dy2); 
   invdt1 = Inverse[matdt1];
   uvar0[[All, 
     1]] = (1 + Exp[(#[[1]] - #[[2]]/Sqrt[2])/Sqrt[6]])^(-2) & /@ 
     sgrid;
   Do[uvar = uvar0[[All, i]]; eqnu = mu uvar (1 - uvar);
    uvar0[[All, i + 1]] = invdt1 . (uvar0[[All, i]] + dt eqnu); 
    uvar0[[top, i + 1]] = uvar0[[top, i + 2]]; 
    uvar0[[left, i + 1]] = uvar0[[left, i + 2]]; 
    uvar0[[right, i + 1]] = uvar0[[right, i + 2]]; 
    uvar0[[bot, i + 1]] = uvar0[[bot, i + 2]];, {i, tmax - 2}]; 
   uvar0];

FDM solution
sol = fdmsol[.1, .1, .1]; // AbsoluteTiming

It takes about 0.231031 s on my laptop that 100 times faster the that with linear FEM above. Visualization
uint = Table[
   Map[Interpolation@Join[sgrid, Transpose@List@#, 2] &, 
     Partition[uvar0[[All, t]], Length[sgrid]]][[1]], {t, 1, 300, 1}];
Table[Plot3D[uint[[i]][x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
  PlotLabel -> Row[{"t =", N[i/300]}], PlotTheme -> "Marketing", 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", MeshStyle -> White], {i, 50, 300, 50}]


Note this plots look similar to that computed with linear FEM. But we can compare solutions sol, U, sol1, sol2 in details to see the wrong solutions generated by NDSolve
Plot[{uint[[300]][x, x], U[300][x, x], sol1[x, x, 1.], 
  sol2[x, x, 1]}, {x, -1, 1}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"FDM", "Linear FEM", "MOL-FEM", "MOL"}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, {Red, Dashed}, Black, {Green, Dashed}}]


I think this is why RIM asked his question, since there are no right solutions with NDSolve at all. Nevertheless maybe with some options we can try use NDSolve as well to solve this problem.
Update 1 As it mentioned by xzczd we can add option to NDSolve so that we can handle jump on the border at t->0,
sol1 = NDSolveValue[{D[u[x, y, t], t] == 
       lambda1  D[u[x, y, t], x, x] + lambda2  D[u[x, y, t], y, y] + 
        mu  u[x, y, t] (1 - u[x, y, t]) /. {lambda1 -> 0.1, 
       lambda2 -> 0.1, mu -> 0.1}, 
     u[x, y, 0] == (1 + Exp[(x - y/Sqrt[2])/Sqrt[6]])^(-2), 
     DirichletCondition[u[x, y, t] == 0, True]}, u, {t, 0, 1}, 
    Element[{x, y}, Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}]], 
    Method -> {"TimeIntegration" -> {"IDA", 
        "MaxDifferenceOrder" -> 2}, 
      "PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
        "DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> {True, 
          "ScaleFactor" -> 100}, 
        "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement"}}}]; // \
AbsoluteTiming

sol2 = NDSolveValue[{D[u[x, y, t], t] == 
     lambda1  D[u[x, y, t], x, x] + lambda2  D[u[x, y, t], y, y] + 
      mu  u[x, y, t] (1 - u[x, y, t]) /. {lambda1 -> 0.1, 
     lambda2 -> 0.1, mu -> 0.1}, 
   u[x, y, 0] == (1 + Exp[(x - y/Sqrt[2])/Sqrt[6]])^(-2), 
   u[-1, y, t] == 0, u[1, y, t] == 0, u[x, -1, t] == 0, 
   u[x, 1, t] == 0}, u, {t, 0, 1}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> {True, "ScaleFactor" -> 100},
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
      "MaxPoints" -> 81, "MinPoints" -> 41, "DifferenceOrder" -> 2}}]

Visualization
Plot[{uint[[300]][x, x], U[300][x, x], sol1[x, x, 1.], 
  sol2[x, x, 1]}, {x, -1, 1}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"FDM", "Linear FEM", "MOL-FEM", "MOL"}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, {Red, Dashed}, {Black, Dotted}, {Green, Dotted}}]



thanks ,is there any way to have the speed of traveling waves  withrespect to time?@Alex Trounev

@RIM Could you explain what are you talking about? What traveling waves you are looking for?

i mean  speed at which the solution of the equation propagates.@Alex Trounev

In a case of parabolic equation considered in your topic we mostly talking about stationary solution that we see on the last picture above. Maybe you are looking for the Korteweg–De Vries equation solution in term of traveling waves?

No it's Fisher kpp eqution ,and i dont undrstand why you get stationary solution , may be ishould change initial data@Alex Trounev

@RIM For Fisher traveling waves we need boundary conditions at infinity like $u(-\infty ,t)=0, u(\infty ,t)=1$

i add this condition but it doesnt work @Alex Trounev i

@RIM Please notice "it doesn't work" isn't an informative response. How do you add the boundary condition? How does it fail? Please clarify, otherwise we won't be able to help you.
